# How to make image onclick to change all the text colors?

Tags: php, html, css

i wanted to add a feature on my website where clicking the image red will turn the whole page's text to red and so on for other colors. I tried doing the code below but it only changes the color that is set between `<h>` but not text in `<div>` or that is styled in css. Sorry if it's a bit confusing. I'm just starting out.

```
<body text="<?PHP echo $_SESSION["textcolor"]; ?>">
<ul>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=1'><img src='images/black.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=2'><img src='images/blanched_almond.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=3'><img src='images/orange.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=4'><img src='images/dark_red.png'></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

*change_color.php*

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$w = $_GET['w'];
switch ($w)
{
    case 1:
        $_SESSION["textcolor"] = "#00000";
    break;
    case 2:
        $_SESSION["textcolor"] = "#ffebcd";
    break;
    case 3:
        $_SESSION["textcolor"] = "ffa500";
    break;
    case 4:
        $_SESSION["textcolor"] = "8b0000";
    break;
}
echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
?>
```

Comment: There is no html property like *text*. You can add style tag and add color = $_SESSION["textcolor"]; 
Like this 
<body style="color: '<?PHP echo $_SESSION["textcolor"]; ?>';">

Comment: Do  you want to stick with doing this in php, which entails a call to the server each time, or would doing it in Javascript on the client side be a possibility?

Comment: I'm learning how to make a basic web right now and i want to do it in a better way. If doing it in javascript is better, it is a possibility @AHaworth

Comment: Why not do this in pure JS?

Comment: If it doesn't work then i might have to do it in JS

Comment: I've noticed that you have a stray closing `</div>` in your code example, and I don't know what you mean by `<h>` - there is no `<h>` - did you mean `<h1>` as in heading? Currently your example only shows a list of links. Your question isn't exactly clear, so please take your time and rephrase it in a way that is easy to understand what's the content of the page you're talking about, how it's structured and what elements on that page you want to re-colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made this way it is not best way I think but I guess it will work for you. Also pay attention where you use '!important' in css.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" data-col="#000000">Black</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-col="#ff0000">Red</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-col="#00ff00">Green</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-col="#0000ff">Blue</a></li>
</ul>

<hr />
<h1>Change colours using the links - without browser refresh!<span>TTTTT</span></h1>
<p>Authoritatively target ethical imperatives for customer directed meta-services. Professionally implement robust platforms through user-centric niches.</p>

<script>
const textNode = (el) => {
    var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
    return a;
}
document.body.onload = () => {
    const colors = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[data-col]'));
    colors.map((value, key) => {
        value.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let node = Array.prototype.slice.call(textNode(document.body));
            node.map((valueNode) => {
                valueNode.parentNode.style.color = value.getAttribute('data-col');
            })
        });
    })
}

</script>
```

Comment: @underrated you must tell me more info about this problem. I do not know right now which images you want to replace with which text

Comment: Thanks! You actually solved my problem! And by 'not the best way' can you explain so that I can take note in the future.

Comment: @underrated By that I meant, I made this solution in 3 minutes, I could not afford more time right now :D

Comment: Oh by the way, is there any way to make the text color stays when going to the next page?

Comment: And can you exclude some class such as footer or button:hover ? Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

The text colour can be set through the `color` CSS property (the `body` elements `text` attribute is deprecated, and inefficient to use) - best done on the `body` element itself, so every child node inherits the styling through CSS.

I am definitely no PHP expert, but I believe the correct way of echoing a value from PHP into an inline value should give you what you need:

```
<body style="color: <?php echo($_SESSION['textcolor']);?>">...</body>
```

EDIT

If you wanted to make this a little more user friendly, you could add client-side JavaScript to handle the colour changes for you. Your HTML and JavaScript code would look something like this (see working demo below):

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="#000000">Black</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="#ff0000">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="#00ff00">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="#0000ff">Blue</a></li>
</ul>

<hr />
<h1>Change colours using the links - without browser refresh!</h1>
<p>Authoritatively target ethical imperatives for customer directed meta-services. Professionally implement robust platforms through user-centric niches.</p>
<div>This is some text inside a div</div>

<script>
  const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[data-col]'));
  links.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.body.style.color = link.getAttribute('data-col');
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code works in any modern browser - without the need for a server, as your single static HTML can be run on its own, even on the file system.

Comment: i did what you told, nothing changes.

Comment: @underrated - I updated my answer with a JavaScript based solution, as it might be more appropriate.

Comment: It doesnt work for text that is inside a div.

Comment: ill ask another question to make it clear.

Comment: The solution I provided I believe solves the problem you described - user selects different colours and the content on the page gets recoloured to that colour - regardless if the text is in a `div` or some other element. Isn't that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

<s>PHP goes through your code line by line. And you send the variable `$_SESSION["textcolor"]` in line 1, but you set a value to it further below. That's why the color tag was empty. You just need to write the PHP code before the HTML code like this:</s>

```php
<?PHP
session_start();
$w=$_GET['w'];
switch($w)
{
    case 1:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#00000";break;
    case 2:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#ffebcd";break;
    case 3:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="ffa500";break;
    case 4:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="8b0000";break;
}
echo "<script>

window.history.back()</script>";

?>

<body text="<?PHP echo $_SESSION["textcolor"];?>">
<ul>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=1'><img src='images/black.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=2'><img src='images/blanched_almond.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=3'><img src='images/orange.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=4'><img src='images/dark_red.png'></a></li></div>
</ul>
</body>
```

I tested it, and works perfectly. :D

I just realized that those are two separate files. The solution is initializing the session in EVERY file that uses the `$_SESSION` variable like this:

```php
<body text="<?PHP session_start(); echo $_SESSION["textcolor"];?>">
```

EDIT: Another thing that you should fix is that your program displays a warning when the `w` search param isn't set. You can fix that by replacing this:

```php
$w=$_GET['w'];
switch($w)
{
    case 1:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#00000";break;
    case 2:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#ffebcd";break;
    case 3:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="ffa500";break;
    case 4:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="8b0000";break;
}
```

with this:

```php
if (isset($_GET['w'])) {
  $w=$_GET['w'];
  switch($w)
  {
    case 1:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#00000";break;
    case 2:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="#ffebcd";break;
    case 3:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="ffa500";break;
    case 4:$_SESSION["textcolor"]="8b0000";break;
  }
}
```

It just checks if `w` is set, and just skips the switch statement if it isn't.

And another thing: The comments said that `text` is not a valid HTML property. It's ancient, and you shouldn't use it for more than messing around or testing stuff, [but it is a property (see the Properties section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body).

Comment: I did what you asked but it only works with code in the <h> section but not in <div>. Even my footer text color didn't change.

Comment: I found the issue and edited my answer. BTW: you should add a filename to every code block if you are posting multiple files, I thought that the two code blocks in your question were in the same file.

Comment: I did what you told but the first thing I saw was my <h1> text turned blue. And when I pasted w search code you gave me, the screen became white when I clicked on the image.

Comment: ill ask another question to make it clear.